# convert an integer value in double to an int type data?

Tags: c++, int

I am quite new to C++ and I want to ask:

"I am always assigning the int or double type data with the same format, such as'int i = 3.;' I know that I can do like this in double type data, but is it OK for int type as well?"

And here is the code I am given:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int i = 3.;
}
```

Comment: this is not C. Who gave you this "instructions" ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think you might want to look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) and [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for some reference on numeric literals.

Comment: Distinguish C and C++. Distinguish instruction and question.

Comment: sorry about my poor expression, i mean that, in C++, can i assign an integer value, which is in flout format like ' 3.0   ', to a variable, which is in int type data?

Comment: I always add a decimal point behind integer like this: int i = 2.;   int i = 3.;

Comment: @KlausBy You should not be doing that. `3.` and `3.0` are not integers, they are `double`s. (Even in maths, 3.0 is a real number, not an integer.)